# how to create something like a cron job scheduler that will keep running?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, cron

I am looking for suggestions on how to create a scheduler that will keep running continuously and do some logic based on current time,something like a cronjob in unix,any guidance is truly appreciated?

I looked at some posts on GOOGLE @ https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23481296/how-to-create-a-job-schedule-using-C-in-a-console-application.html but I dont think this satisfies my requirement?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class ThreadWork 
{
   public static void DoWork()
   {
while(true)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 17&DateTime.Now.Minute==0&DateTime.Now.Second==0)
                {
                   myMethod();
              Thread.Sleep(1000*60);
                }
              Thread.Sleep(1000*60);
            }
   }
}
class ThreadTest
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(ThreadWork.DoWork);
      Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
      myThread.Start();
   }
}
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591271/A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp

Comment: Why not just create the functionality you need and use Windows Task Scheduler to run it at certain times?

Comment: If you need this to be running inside a web application you should consider not reinventing the wheel and use a framework like [Hangfire.io](https://www.hangfire.io/) or [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying out quartz.net - https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

You can create separate tasks that execute at different intervals.  The main class would be a job scheduler that would look something like this:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail emailJob = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().StoreDurably().WithIdentity("massEmail", "emailGroup").Build();


        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                            .WithIdentity("massEmailTrigger", "emailGroup")
                            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                                .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                                .RepeatForever())
                            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
    }
}
```

The job would looks something like this:

```
public class EmailJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Execute the task here....
    }
}
```

Then you would start it in your global_asax application_start method like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    JobScheduler.Start();
}
```

Check out the examples on the website...there's a lot of different time configurations that you can use.